# How to get javascript value using Nokogiri?

Tags: screen-scraping, nokogiri

I need to pull out a particular line that is in some inline javascript on a page using nokogiri. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: By inline JavaScript you mean that a call like `document.write` is producing visual content on the page? If so, you can't do this with Nokogiri unless you have some other tool that runs JS and produces the equivalent markup for the corresponding DOM changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
doc.css('script').each do |script|
    puts script.content
end
```